# Application.ThreadException for ALL exception? Not just un-trapped ones?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to create a top level exception capture for a debug version of some real-time data capture software and was wondering if there was a top-level exception handler similar to Application.ThreadException that captures ALL exceptions, not just unhandled/trapped ones.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to be *notified* of all exceptions, you can use the [AppDomain.FirstChanceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception%28VS.100%29.aspx) event.

Note: This is only available in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Nice option--but is only for .NET 4.0 and up.

Comment: I believe the only *other* answer is to actually write a debugger and have it attach to the process being monitored. This is likely more difficult than upgrading to .NET 4.0. :)

Comment: Agreed, only a debugger could get the first chance notification.  A program cannot debug itself.

Answer (score 2):

*ALL* exceptions inherit System.Exception.  This would be your top-level that you can trap on.

Comment: Right, but I was asking specifically for already handled exceptions. Probably should have been more clear, but this was essentially for real time/ uninterrupted logging. 

Upped for my ambiguity